# limit access to some functions with a flag in python

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project that calls webservice for login and if the login information was valid, the webservice returns a flag.
I want to use that flag and if it is True, let the user see other pages and if it was false, return to login page.

in the beginning, the login database was on my side and I used Django user_passes_test, in the new style, I made a simple decorator simple decorator that returns True or False, and it seems that doesn't work that way, and I searched for some Django feature and found nothing.

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        flag = 
            LoginWebservice(username=username,password=password)
        request.session['flag'] = flag
        if user_login_reasult == True:
            return redirect(reverse('basic_app:HomePage'))
        else:
            return redirect(reverse('basic_app:login'))


def login_ws_check(request):
    try:
        if("flag" in request.session):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    except Exception as e:
        messages.info(request, e)
        return False

@login_ws_check
def HomePage(request):
    return render(request , 'basic_app/HomePage.html') 

@login_ws_check
def OtherPage(request):
    return render(request , 'basic_app/OtherPage.html')
```

i expect if the login flag is True , let me in and if not , redirect me to login page. and none of the ways I've tried working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't at all how you write a decorator. You need to accept the function being wrapped, and define and return an inner function that wraps the original function and calls it if necessary.

```
def login_ws_check(func):
    def wrapped(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if("flag" in request.session):
            return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
    return wrapped
```